# Ruby On Rails - Brakeman: Session cookies should be set to HTTP only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, brakeman

I am using `Brakeman` `gem` to analyse my `ruby-on-rails` app code.

It have the following `High level security warning`:

```
Warning Type    | Message                                                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Session Setting | Session cookies should be set to HTTP only near line 3 |
```

According to the [documentation](http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/session_setting/), setting the `httponly` attribute to `true`, rather than `false`(default value), inside the `config/initializers/session_sotre.rb` removes this warning(it worked for me).

Can someone explain what is happening? Why is it solving this problem? is setting the value to `true` can cause a problem?

Comment: the check spelling does weird things from time to time... Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Rails sets the `HTTPOnly` flag on session cookies. This flag disallows JavaScript from reading the cookie ([see here for details](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly)) and thus prevents [cross-site scripting attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A3-Cross-Site_Scripting_(XSS)) from accessing the cookie. In the case of session cookies, it prevents the stealing/hijacking sessions via cross-site scripting.

Setting `httponly: false` in the session store options turns off this protection. You can either set it to `true` or don't set it at all (in which case the default is still `true`).

However, if an application needs to access the session cookie from JavaScript for some reason, then you have to turn off the `httponly` option. This should be pretty rare, however.

Comment: Justin - if you are building an front-end application with, for example, React, you'd have to turn off the HTTPOnly flag right, so that React can have access to the cookies?

Comment: Why would React need to read the *session* cookie? The cookies are sent to the server regardless of the `httponly` flag. The flag prevents JavaScript from actually accessing the cookie value.